# EACF tables with the numbers in r

Tags: r, time-series

I have a series named logReturn, I am trying to determine the order of an ARMA process. (Note: logReturn is stationary.) To this end I have just used eacf function. It refers to ARMA(0,0), as it is showed below.

```
eacf(na.omit(usdtry$logReturn), ar.max = 7, ma.max = 13)

AR/MA
  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
0 o o o o o o o o x o o  o  o  x 
1 x o o o x o o o x o o  o  o  x 
2 x x o o o o o o o o o  o  o  x 
3 x x x o o o o o o o o  o  o  x 
4 x x x x o o o o o o o  o  o  x 
5 x x x x x o o o o o o  o  o  x 
6 x x x x x x o o o o o  o  o  x 
7 x x x x x x x o o o o  o  o  x
```

Here is the question: As eacf() function only gives the symbols, I was wondering if I can see the exact numbers behind it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you can.

From the example in the documentation:

```
data(arma11.s)
ESACF <- eacf(arma11.s)
```

And to get the actual numbers:

```
ESACF$eacf
```

Output:

```
           [,1]       [,2]        [,3]         [,4]       [,5]        [,6]          [,7]        [,8]        [,9]      [,10]
[1,]  0.7306776  0.4660120  0.35608109  0.255438796 0.15855639  0.07671343  0.0845558970  0.03425112  0.04385366 0.09543669
[2,]  0.2095843 -0.2024517  0.03089843  0.076548162 0.08227227 -0.16809867  0.0888265424 -0.09530559 -0.01675742 0.09515195
[3,]  0.5040561 -0.1108708  0.06332267  0.012965322 0.02753716 -0.05821879 -0.0008396188 -0.06149982 -0.03426046 0.07408780
[4,]  0.3674307  0.2258370  0.13673940 -0.010634281 0.03502736 -0.04934294 -0.0020820351 -0.18003648  0.02060658 0.05557071
[5,] -0.2431391 -0.1967037  0.23577748  0.053755999 0.01355323 -0.02844293 -0.0086894767 -0.16966037  0.06603945 0.03508668
[6,] -0.2738476 -0.1045300  0.18663583  0.007894465 0.01097416 -0.03923744 -0.0021858164 -0.19103072  0.06846740 0.07683705
[7,]  0.3584490  0.1947224  0.16888088  0.003309865 0.30169475 -0.03965688  0.0138995618 -0.21468358  0.05780874 0.05679359
[8,]  0.5069406  0.0313976 -0.18568982 -0.019630435 0.37137623  0.11942316 -0.0015135671 -0.16198402 -0.02325274 0.10554957
            [,11]        [,12]         [,13]         [,14]
[1,]  0.090861366  0.062083089  4.819929e-02  0.0399006628
[2,]  0.071992733  0.010955894 -3.116564e-05  0.0481609830
[3,]  0.034227976  0.003369403  4.803725e-04  0.0614502739
[4,]  0.047902402 -0.001928911  6.143485e-03  0.0628228467
[5,] -0.003550315  0.015328572 -3.231288e-02  0.0006093876
[6,]  0.010722453  0.046820091 -3.232496e-02 -0.0042187234
[7,] -0.004548155  0.027150408 -4.363450e-02 -0.0167052767
[8,]  0.084177867  0.051593290 -3.621192e-02 -0.0007006141
```